# jQuery button to check all check boxes issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a button that checks all checkboxes in a `div` and un-checks.

However if I were to manually check one checkbox, then hit the Check all button and then uncheck all, the checkbox which was manually checked does not become unchecked!

Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/hM5bu/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thats because jQuery was changed in 1.6

Using `attr` instead of `prop` is what is breaking it.

Try using `prop` instead

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hM5bu/2/

See this question: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) for more about `prop` and `attr` in jQuery 1.6

Comment: @AJFMEDIA remember to select an `accepted answer` when you can ^_^

Comment: Yikes. This makes moving to 1.6 a big deal.

Comment: @Jeff, they fixed the problem in [jQuery 1.6.1](http://itknowledgehub.com/development-integration/jquery-1-6-1-rc-1-released/)

Comment: @Jeff, just make sure to get 1.6.1 and **not** 1.6

Comment: @jeff this is the official 1.6.1 link: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/10/jquery-1-6-1-rc-1-released/

Answer (score -1):

here is a solution:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="todos" id="todos" /> All<br/>
<input class="marcartodos" type="checkbox" name="marcado[]" value="1" />1<br/>
<input class="marcartodos" type="checkbox" name="marcado[]" value="2" />2<br/>
<input class="marcartodos" type="checkbox" name="marcado[]" value="3" />3<br/>
<input class="marcartodos" type="checkbox" name="marcado[]" value="4" />4<br/>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

$("#todos").click(function() {                          
if ($(this).is(':checked'))                         
$(".marcartodos").attr('checked', true);
else 
$(".marcartodos").attr('checked', false);
});

});

</script>
```

Comment: that **DOES NOT** solve it at all! it has the same problem: http://jsfiddle.net/hM5bu/3/

Comment: Yes, you are right, @Neal. The attr() method doesn't work on jQuery 1.6. Sorry.